# OpenCV: transforming 3 channel image into 4 channel

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to change 3-channel image into 4-channel like this:

```
cv::VideoCapture video;
video.open("sample.avi");
cv::Mat source;
cv::Mat newSrc;
int from_to = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3 };
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ )
{
   video >> source;
   cv::mixChannels ( source, 2, newSrc, 1, from_to, 4 );
}
```

Then I got

```
too many input arguments in function call
```

for the 'mixChannels' line. Besides, I am not sure whether I am giving the arguments correctly for my goal. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can convert 3 channel image to 4 channel as follows:

```
cv::Mat source = cv::imread(path);

cv::Mat newSrc(source.size(), CV_MAKE_TYPE(source.depth(), 4));

int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 2,3 };

cv::mixChannels(&source,1,&newSrc,1,from_to,4);
```

This way channel 4 will be a duplicate of channel 3. By using a negative number in the `from_to` list, the output channel is zero filled. eg:

```
int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, -1,3 };
```

Comment: in C++11 you can also use the more convenient form `cv::mixChannels({{src, ...}}, {{dst1, ...}}, { 2,0, 1,1, 0,2, 3,3 })`.

Comment: @sgarizvi Though myself being a complete novice in OpenCV. How `mixChannels(...)` is different from     `cvtColor(motion,newmotion,CV_BGR2BGRA);`

Answer (score 7):

What is the 4th channel supposed to contain?
How about:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
Mat frame;
cap >> frame;

Mat RGBA(frame.size(), CV_8UC4, camData);
cv::cvtColor(frame, RGBA, CV_BGR2RGBA, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I don't know what should the 4th channel contain, actually my main goal is to use "meanShiftFiltering", but it only accepts 4-channel image. So that is why I need to change. And what is "camData" in your code here? Did you mean "frame.data" ?

Comment: it should contain alpha (transparency)?

Answer (score 7):

I think it should be like this:

```
cv::Mat source = cv::imread(path);
cv::Mat newSrc = cv::Mat(source.rows,source.cols,CV_8UC4);

int from_to[] = { 0,0, 1,1, 2,2, 3,3 };
cv::mixChannels(&source,1,&newSrc,1,from_to, source.channels());
```

In C++11 you can use initializer lists to provide multiple matrices for batch conversion inline:

```
cv::mixChannels({{source}}, {{newSrc}}, from_to, source.channels());
```

We set 3 pairs to be copied, so this leaves the 4 channel empty in newsrc. And 1 in the second and forth parameter means that the pointers source and newSrc point to one element to be processed. The last parameter gives the length of from_to.

Comment: Imho, this should be the accepted answer. The answer by @sgarizvi has some issues (at least for OpenCV 3.2.0+), resulting in failed assertations, if the input image does not already contain 4 channels: the `from_to` array requires a mapping for each channel in the input array (one can solve this by passing `source.channels()` for `npairs`. Also the accepted answer has an invalid value for `nscrs`, which should be *1*.