# OpenCV Image Shape Error - : could not broadcast input array from shape (585,828,3) into shape (585,828,4)

Tags: opencv, python

I receive the error in the title when trying to import certain images. All images are .PNG, however, some work while others don't. I understand that this is due to the third parameter in shape. What does the third parameter represent?

I have been looking in the cv2 shape documentation and can not find it.

Comment: The third parameter is the number of channels in the image (this first two number are height and width). For example, a RGB image of size 400x400 would have a img.shape = 400,400,3. A grayscale image of the same size would have a img.shape = 400,400,1.

Comment: Are you aware of a method for increasing the number of channels by one on exported images?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451936/opencv-transforming-3-channel-image-into-4-channel Found it